# Different rsync behavior for identical directory name

Tags: rsync

I want to synchronize 2 codebases. The below command is working great, except that it doesn't account for one use case that I have with 2 directories named **test** in different locations:

- /test/
- /start/test/

`$ rsync -avCz --delete-before --progress --exclude=test /tmp/codebase/ .`

What I want to do is to exclude the **/test** directory completely from the rsync but I do want **/start/test** to be rsync'ed.

I'd prefer not to have to come up with a static TXT file that I should pass as an argument to rsync. Is there any way to achieve this otherwise? Playing with **--include** VS **--exclude** and a trailing slash (*--exclude=test/*) didn't work as anticipated for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a leading `/` to match only in the root of the transfer. Try this:

```
rsync -avCz --delete-before --progress --exclude=/test/ /tmp/codebase/ .
```

Here is the man page snippet for the leading `/`:

> if the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular spot in the hierarchy of files, otherwise it is matched against the end of the pathname.  This is  similar  to a leading ^ in regular expressions.  Thus "/foo" would match a name of "foo" at either the "root of the transfer" (for a global rule) or in the merge-file’s directory (for a per-directory rule).  An unqualified "foo" would match a name of "foo" anywhere in the tree because the algorithm is applied recursively from the top down;  it
>                 behaves  as if each path component gets a turn at being the end of the filename.  Even the unanchored "sub/foo" would match at any point in the hierarchy where a "foo" was
>                 found within a directory named "sub".

And for the trailing `/`:

> if the pattern ends with a / then it will only match a directory, not a regular file, symlink, or device.

#### Update

I am guessing from you comments that you are also looking for the `--delete-excluded` option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work for my use case.

Comment: @anavarre, what was the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. It didn't do anything different than passing `--exclude=test` or `--exclude=test/` - That is, no change in my **/start/test** directory.

Comment: @anavarre, if you `start/test` directory is already there then you need `--delete-excluded`.

Comment: Do you mean that it'd replace `--delete-before` completely? I did try by simply adding `--delete-excluded` instead of `--delete-before` and by adding both parameters. In one way like with the other, it fails to do what I want (even worse, it seems to wipe everything while I do know everything's up-to-date but **/start/test**). I'm aiming at only have rsync to sync the changes performed on the source (that is, update any number of new/updated/deleted files within **/start/test/**)

Comment: @anavarre, apologies, I have misread the question. You need a leading slash so that `test` is only matched in the root of the transfer.

Comment: No worries! Before I asked this question I did try `--exclude=/test/` and any variation (no leading slash, no trailing slash, one or the other...). Unfortunately, it is never working the way I want.

Comment: @anavarre, the leading/trailing `/` should work, unless somehow you have an old version of `rsync` that doesn't support them. I have used this stuff on many scripts of my own. If the `test` exists before the transfer you need to remove it manually or add `--delete-excluded` so that `rsync` will remove it.

Comment: FYI rsync version is **3.1.0-2I** (Kubuntu Trusty) - I can't remove the `test` dir since it has files that should not be deleted ever during the rsync process. This is why it's been excluded completely from the process in first place. I think I'm gonna try and create an equivalent architecture for testing the rsync parameters further.

Comment: I've just accepted your answer because it does work in an equivalent architecture, not just in my prod thingy. This is thus another story that I need to sort out. Thanks for your time!